# What's the best way to access one Connect middleware from another?

Tags: node.js, express, connect

I've written a Connect middleware where I'd like to re-use the "send" method of the "static" Connect middleware if it's installed. What's the best way to get a hold of that code in my middleware? Currently I'm passing the express object use "use"ing my middleware, sort of like this:

```
app.use(myMiddleware(express, options));
```

then myMiddleware calls

```
express.static.send(req, res, next, ...)
```

That works, but feels a bit clunky. Is there a better way?

Comment: What do you have currently? Can we see a gist or a github or something? Might be a need to rearchitect something. I honestly don't do Express/Connect, but I'm always willing to take a poke to see what new things I can learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// myMiddleware.js
var connect = require("connect");
var send = connect.static.send

// package.json
...
"dependencies": { 
   "connect": "1.x"
}
```

Simply, get it directly from connect, add connect as dependency to your module.

Comment: Will that get an existing configure "static" middleware (with the user's expiration settings, etc). Or will that create a new one?

Comment: OK, thanks. Know of a way to get an already-configured instance if there is one?

Comment: @KevinDente inherit from static and ask the user to configure your module with the static configurements